# Flask-SQLAlchemy via amazon RDS

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python, rds

My Flask-SQLAlchemy has connection via Amazon, RDS to MySQL but there is the problem when i want to put anything in my database in Russian language all my notes recieves in templates  as ???? instead of letters. when i use english there is no problem but how i can use Russian language?

Below is my configuration:

```
 app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123'
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://flask:@flasktest.cuncoak8uz9k.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com/flasktestdb'
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

class User(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)


     new = User(name = 'Дмитрий') # name written in Russian language
     {{new.name}} # i receive ??????? instead of a Дмитрий
```

How a can receive new.name in a language which i wrote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that RDS encodes databases in Latin-1 by default. You want your database to be encoded in utf-8. 
You can easily find how to do that on the web, but [this post on AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94921) details quite well the steps.

In short : create a db parameter group specifying correct encoding. Recreates your database with a previously created dump of which you ensured that specify utf-8 in the encoding. All previous data (the "???????") cannot be converted to utf-8 (You may need to clean-up that). I just hope for you that it was not production data.